# Why can we only talk about derivatives on an open interval?

Tags: calculus

For instance, in my calculus class, all theorems are in the following form:

For example, Rolle's theorem:
If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ ... (etc)

My question is, when presented with a closed interval, why must we talk about its derivatives on an open interval? Why doesn't Rolle's theorem say `differentiable on $[a,b]$' instead of $(a,b)$

Comment: If it's not defined on $x<a$, then how can you take the limit from the left?

Comment: Derivatives are limits, so you need some room around a point in order to talk about the limit.

Comment: You can have a closed interval, it just needs to be specified what is the derivative in the endpoints. Either it can be defined using one-sided neighborhoods, or as a derivative of some smooth extension.

Comment: We can say that $f$ has derivative in close interval $[a,b]$ but it's only right\left derivative on $a$ \ $b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @PeterFrank says in the comments, one can talk about so-called **one-sided differentiability** in the end points, e.g.

$$
f'(a)=\lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}. 
$$

But the point is that if you only assume that $f$ **has to be** differentiable on $(a,b)$, the theorem is **better/stronger**.

For example, we **can** apply Rolle to $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$, **although** this map is **not** one-sidedly differentiable in $0$.

If you would assume that $f$ **has to be** differentiable on $[0,1]$, you could **not** apply Rolle in this case.

Comment: So, if we have a closed interval $[a,b]$ and we try to find the limit of $a$ we can only talk about the one sided limit (from the right side).  But if we have an open interval where $c$ is in $(a,b)$ we can talk about both sides of the limit?

Comment: Yes, because for such a $c$, the function $f$ is defined "to the left of $c$ **and** "to the right of $c$", so we can consider the limit from both sides. In contrast, the square root is not defined "left of $0$", so that it makes no sense to consider the left-sided derivative (which intuitively is the slope if you approach the point from the left) at $0$.

Comment: If we have an open continuous interval $(a, b)$ for a function $f$, is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x\to a^+$? I don't think it is but would like to hear your answer and a brief explanation if possible, please. Thank you.

Comment: I meant if we have a continuous function $f$ on an open interval $(a, b)$.

Comment: @LarsSmith - No, the answer already gives a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

**For this reason:** (*I talk about **Mean Value Theorem** here*)
If we consider differentiability on the closed interval $\mathbf[a, b\mathbf]$, we are then losing the generality of our theorem; because we're asking for a *more strict* condition to be satisfied.
Meanwhile, considering differentiability on $\mathbf(a, b\mathbf)$ makes the theorem *more general* and *stronger* without affecting the validity of our theorem.

For example, take a look at the graph of the semicircle with radius $1$
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}
$$
where $f(x)$ is continuous on its domain $\mathbf[-1,1\mathbf]$, but it happens to be differentiable *only* on $\mathbf(-1, 1\mathbf)$

And my point is that, with the *stricter* closed interval condition; this function is **not** qualified, even though there *really* is a point $\mathbf{c}$ in $\mathbf(a, b\mathbf)$ where the slope of the tangent there is equal to that of the secant cutting through the endpoints $\mathbf{a}$ & $\mathbf{b}$.
And as far as I know, and as far as I am convinced, there doesn't exist a function where you'd need such a strict condition for the theorem to remain true.

So, we conclude that there is *not* any need for considering differentiability on a closed interval instead of an open one; since that'd cause a loss of generality for no acceptable reason.

And as always, Allah S.W.T. knows best. I hope this helps insha'Allah.